# How to replace default user-agent sent with gRPC request in basic gRPC implementation using .NET Grpc.Net.* packages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I've noticed that, if I sent a gRPC request using .NET Grpc.Net.* implementation, the client automatically attaches some headers to the request. Please consider the following snippet:

```
public class Dummy
{
    private readonly OrderingService.OrdersClient _ordersClient;
    private readonly IDateTimeProvider _dateTimeProvider;

    public Dummy(
        OrderingService.OrdersClient ordersClient, 
        IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
    {
        _ordersClient = ordersClient;
        _dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task<GetOrdersResponseModel> GetOrderInfoAsync(GetOrdersRequestModel request)
    {
        var deadline = _dateTimeProvider.UtcTimestamp.AddMilliseconds(5000);

        var response = await _ordersClient.GetOrdersAsync(
            request,
            deadline: deadline);

        ...
    }
}
```

Don't mind the simplicity of this snippet - it's just for example purposes. In here I inject the gRPC client, and I don't set any user-agent metadata header. If I inspected the request metadata on the server side in that case I get the following string:

```
Headers: {x-grpc-full-method-name=xxx, grpc-accept-encoding=identity,gzip,deflate, traceparent=xxx, content-type=application/grpc, user-agent=grpc-dotnet/2.49.0 (.NET 6.0.4; CLR 6.0.4; net6.0; windows; x64), grpc-timeout=984m}
```

The gRPC client adds some info about the user-agent automatically. If I tried to set the user-agent header value manually using the following code:

```
public class Dummy
{
    private readonly OrderingService.OrdersClient _ordersClient;
    private readonly IDateTimeProvider _dateTimeProvider;

    public Dummy(
        OrderingService.OrdersClient ordersClient, 
        IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
    {
        _ordersClient = ordersClient;
        _dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task<GetOrdersResponseModel> GetOrderInfoAsync(GetOrdersRequestModel request)
    {
        var deadline = _dateTimeProvider.UtcTimestamp.AddMilliseconds(5000);
        var metadata = new Metadata { { "user-agent", "foo" } };

        var response = await _ordersClient.GetOrdersAsync(
            request,
            metadata,
            deadline: deadline);

        ...
    }
}
```

I get something like this:

```
Headers: {x-grpc-full-method-name=xxx, grpc-accept-encoding=identity,gzip,deflate, traceparent=xxx, content-type=application/grpc, user-agent=grpc-dotnet/2.49.0 (.NET 6.0.4; CLR 6.0.4; net6.0; windows; x64) foo, grpc-timeout=984m}
```

The "foo" has been concatenated to the user-agent header, but I'd like to replace the whole string in there. So I wish to have that one:

```
Headers: {x-grpc-full-method-name=xxx, grpc-accept-encoding=identity,gzip,deflate, traceparent=xxx, content-type=application/grpc, user-agent=foo, grpc-timeout=984m}
```

How to achieve that using .NET implementation for gRPC?? Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to use the AddHeaders method in the CallOptions to achieve this. Can you share the content of the GetOrdersAsync method?